# Stop arrow keys changing pages when on Google.com

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, hotkeys

I find that when I type search terms into a browser, suggestions come up. Not from history but popular search terms. Fine.

But When I hold the forward arrow to put the cursor at the end of what i've typed,(not talking about using the end key), it completes what I write from popular search terms.

I want to stop this behavior.

As an example, if I type min (cursor is at end), then I push the right arrow, it completes it to say minefield.  So if the cursor were in the middle and I held right arrow it'd have the same effect. I want to remove this effect.

This happens in Chrome or IE so is an issue with using Google.com  I'm interested in good ways to deal with this so arrow keys function normally

Comment: What do you want the right arrow to do instead? That might be an easier question to answer.

Comment: @ChrisF well what it normally does, move the cursor through the text. this is in the google search box, I don't want it to complete which it does based on popular search terms

Comment: it's not just chrome, but any browser. IE too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your question correctly. The effect you are talking about is **Google Instant**.

To disable that feature completely do this on the **Google** page.

Click the little *gear* on the top right corner.

[image]

Click **Search settings**.

[image]

Check the radio button that says **Do not use Google Instant**.

[image]

Doing so will disable the feature you are talking about where **pushing** the right arrow *autocompletes* the search term.

---

This is what happens when **Google Instant** is enabled:
**Notice the little gray autocompleted phrase*

[image]

This is with **Google Instant** disabled:
*There is no autocompleted phrase and if you **push** the right arrow, it does not autocomplete it for you*

[image]

Comment: click the right arrow?  I don't know about you but I push the right arrow! nevertheless.. this works!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on chrome 14.0.801.0 , and noticed that what you described does not happen on the unified search / addressbar. However, it does happen on the www.google.com website, but does not happen on the www.bing.com site.

I infer that this is the intended behavior of the site programmed by Google programmers.

You could create your own search page using basic HTML, save it on your computer, add a bookmark or an entry into your host file (assuming you are using windows) and use a simpler search box that does not annoy you.